# Unable to locate driver for the xv-11 Lidar on kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node) all I need to type in to install the driver on Kinetic is:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-xv-11-laser-driver
```

When I enter this to the command line it tells me:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-xv-11-laser-driver
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253208/unable-to-locate-driver-for-the-xv-11-lidar-on-kinetic?/) by [Josh Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/29190/josh-smith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the average case, the tutorial is correct: using `apt-get` (or whatever the package manager is on the particular Linux distribution that you are using) is the preferred way to install (ROS) packages.

In this particular case however, it would appear that the `xv_11_laser_driver` package has not been released into Kinetic yet, so you cannot install the binaries and will have to build the package from source. See #q252478 for some help on how to do that correctly (the question title mentions *Ubuntu Mate*, but the instructions should work on all Linux distributions that ROS supports).

PS: you can deduce that the package hasn't been released for Kinetic yet by looking at its wiki page: [wiki/xv_11_laser_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/xv_11_laser_driver). Note how the version rocker at the top of the page only has buttons for *hydro* and *indigo*, but not for Kinetic. Another way to find out what has been released for a particular release of ROS are the status pages. [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=xv_11](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=xv_11) shows the status of `xv_11_laser_driver` in Kinetic. Note that no package is listed (while [the same page for Indigo](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=xv_11) does show the package).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1